# How to get post script name of type1 fonts on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, postscript

How to get post script name,full path of type 1 font on 64 bit Windows7? APIs for these are provided by Adobe ATM library for 32 bit win OS only like- ATMGetPostScriptName, ATMGetFontPaths, etc.

As per my knowledge type 1 fonts are supported by OS now. I am able to get all these font information through GetFontData, RegQueryMultipleValues, etc for TTF and OTF fonts but these APIs are failing for type1 fonts (.pfm, .pfb fonts).

First time I am using this forum and hoping someone can help me out quickly.

Thanks in Advance,
Vijendra

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I wanted the postscript name and to convert the font to postscript. The solution sits in a little library called ttf2pt1, found at http://ttf2pt1.sourceforge.net/README.html

The routine you need is below. The routine digs out all the various internal names for the font using OutlineTextMetrics. The nameFace value is the one you want.

```
short i;
short val;
long offset;
OUTLINETEXTMETRIC *otm;
UINT nSize;
UINT retVal;
char *sptr;
char *nameFamily;
char *nameFace;
char *nameStyle;
char *nameFull;
int fontType;
char otmBuffer[4096];

SelectObject(hdc, theFont);
nSize = GetOutlineTextMetrics(hdc, 0, NULL);
if(nSize){
    otm = (OUTLINETEXTMETRIC *) otmBuffer;
    retVal = GetOutlineTextMetrics(hdc, nSize, otm);

    val = otm->otmTextMetrics.tmPitchAndFamily;

    offset = (long) otm->otmpFamilyName;
    sptr = &otmBuffer[offset];
    nameFamily = sptr;
    offset = (long) otm->otmpFaceName;
    sptr = &otmBuffer[offset];
    nameFace = sptr;
    offset = (long) otm->otmpStyleName;
    sptr = &otmBuffer[offset];
    nameStyle = sptr;
    offset = (long) otm->otmpFullName;
    sptr = &otmBuffer[offset];
    nameFull = sptr;

    if(val & TMPF_TRUETYPE){
        fontType = kFontTypeTrueType;
    }
    else{
        if(val & TMPF_VECTOR){
            fontType = kFontTypePostscript;
        }
    }
}
else{
    fontType = kFontTypeUnknown;
}
```